# Почему программа проскакивает 2 считывания чисел?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HourseNask
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, y, deskSize;
            Console.Write("Enter size of the board ");
            deskSize = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("x = ");
            x = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("y = ");
            y = Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код на C#. Почему-то deskSize считывается, потом просто идет вывод в консоль

```
x=
y=
```

и программа завершает свое действие. То есть x и y не считываются, хотя описаны точно также.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `Console.Read()` забирает максимально возможное кол-во подходящих символов из буфера ввода расположенных до символа новой строки - "\n" ( который она НЕ удаляет )

Таким образом ваша программа работает так:

1. `Console.Write("Enter size of the board ");` - вывод
2. Пользователь набирает "123" и нажимает `Enter`, сл-но в буфере ввода "123\n"
3. `deskSize = Console.Read();` - забираем из буфера ввода "123", остаётся "\n"
4. `Console.WriteLine("x = ");` - вывод
5. `x = Console.Read();` - в буфере ввода ( "\n" ) не встречается подходящих данных, пишем в `X` - 0
6. `Console.WriteLine("y = ");`- вывод
7. `y = Console.Read();` - в буфере ввода ( "\n" ) не встречается подходящих данных, пишем в `Y` - 0

Т.е. проблема в том, что в буфере ввода остаётся символ новой строки - "\n".
Решается так, как сказал [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre): 
Заменяем `Console.Read()` на `Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() )`

P.S: Если не прав - поправьте ( с C# не работал )

Comment: или ``Console.Read()`` на ``Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())``

Comment: первое не помогло

Comment: второе тоже(

Comment: да. заменил везде. но не пашет.

Comment: почему тогда у меня работает? [пруф](http://4put.ru/pictures/max/215/663097.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Костыль для решения данной проблемы => Использовать в холостую вызов консольного метода `Console.ReadLine()`, до вызова метода `Console.Read()`. `Console.ReadLine()` - считывает все управляющие символы, которые мешают нормальной работе `Console.Read()`.